# Symfony service injection to action

Tags: symfony

I am trying to have the SwiftMailer service made available to me in a action using the following technique:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#fetching-and-using-services

```
public function submitAction (Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
        $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
        var_dump($mailer);
}
```

This is the error:

> Controller "AppBundle\Controller\QuoteController::submitAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$mailer" argument. Either
>   the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no
>   default value has been provided or because there is a non optional
>   argument after this one.

The `var_dump` tells me this is not empty - I recently upgraded to Symfony 3.3.10 and changes my services.yml to the following:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services are normally (and can be automatically) injected into the constructor.

They can also be automatically put into the action method parameters, but [the controller must be tagged to enable it].(http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html)

```
# controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
# and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

The Request (and since 3.2+, SessionInterface and User/UserInterface, among others) are detected with the in-built PHP Reflection api. There's a more specialised subsystem to be able recognise and automatically add them, with `ArgumentResolver` (using `SessionValueResolver` and `ServiceValueResolver`) - beyond the existing `ParameterConverter` (used for fetching entities from parameter IDs for the action method parameters).

Comment: I was wondering whether that was it or not. However, I am curious, how does the Request get injected if the controller is not tagged? I will try this right away and accept your answer if it works - thank you :)

Comment: Just for info, the request object has always been handled as a special case and is not directly related to the new action injection functionality.  Request is a bit unique because Symfony supports nested requests and it's important that actions receive the current request.